# Extract specific columns from file with shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix

I have a huge text file, from which I want to extract specific columns. I can do this in python, but as the file has ~1.2 billion lines, this is way to slow. The file looks like this (one line shown):

```
chr1    9734    10486   ID=SRX502813;Name=Input%20control%20(@%20IMR-90);Title=GSM1358818:%20HIRA%20OIS%20Control%20input%20DNA%3B%20Homo%20sapiens%3B%20ChIP-Seq;Cell%20group=Lung;<br>source_name=Fibroblasts;cell%20line=IMR90;chip%20antibody=none; 1000    .   9734    10486   255,0,0
```

Now, I would like to extract the first three columns and the ID, which is part of the fourth column:

```
chr1    9734    10486   SRX502813
```

I can extract the first three columns with the following code, but i can't get the splitting of the substring in the 4th column to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# -*- coding: None -*-
end_of_file=0
while [[ $end_of_file == 0 ]]; do
  read -r line
  end_of_file=$?
  grep SRX* | cut -f 1-3 >> out_file.txt
done < "$1"
```

Possibly someone can provide a hint on how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the 4th column always starts with `ID=` followed by the ID, followed by `;` and assuming the first 3 columns don't contain `ID=`, you can use `sed` like this

```
sed 's/ID=\([^;]*\);.*/\1/' inputfile
```

This captures a sequence of characters except `;`  after `ID=`. In case the ID is not always terminated with a `;` You can use an alternative pattern that searches for a sequence of alphanumeric characters

```
sed 's/ID=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*/\1/' inputfile
```

When I create a file `inputfile` that contains exactly the line from the question, I get the result

```
chr1    9734    10486   SRX502813
```

In case you want to extract only the lines that contain `ID=SRX` you can combine this with fgrep

```
fgrep 'ID=SRX' inputfile | sed 's/ID=\([^;]*\);.*/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
That leaves me with the following line:
`chr1 9734 10486 ID=SRX502813
Name=Input%20control%20(@%20IMR-90)
Title=GSM1358818:%20HIRA%20OIS%20Control%20input%20DNA%3B%20Homo%20sapiens%3B%20ChIP-Seq
Cell%20group=Lung
<br>source_name=Fibroblasts
cell%20line=IMR90
chip%20antibody=none`

How do I get rid of the last text block starting with `name` ?

Comment: `awk -F'Name' '{print $1}' inputfile`

Comment: @tirichl Is your input exactly as in the question? If not, please edit your question and show the problematic input lines. The line in your comment does not have a `;` immediately after the ID. Please specify in your question the exact format (or possible formats) of the ID field.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk.

```
awk -F';' '{sub(/ID=/,"");print $1}' inputfile
```